# Is there such a thing as a participle phrase?

Tags: participles, dependent-clause, attributive-adjectives

1. Look at the girl *dancing on the stage*.
2. Look at the *dancing* girl.
3. They are a *happily married* couple.
4. The Japanese are now a *meat-eating* people.

I understand that "dancing on the stage" in the first sentence is considered a *clause* (a reduced relative clause). What about the others? Could any one of them be considered a participle *phrase* rather than a clause (when used attributively, i.e. prepositively)?

Comment: What you describe as a *participle phrase* would often be described as a *verb phrase*.  The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* would regard *dancing* as either a verb or a VP depending on the meaning in (2). In (3) *married* is an adjective. In (4) *meat-eating* is a compound adjective. Don't have any authoritative references (as in page numbers etc), and nor am I certain, so this is just a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [1] *Look at the girl dancing on the stage*.
>
> [2] *Look at the dancing girl.*
>
> [3] *They are a happily married couple.*
>
> [4] *The Japanese are now a meat-eating people.*

As you say, in [1] "dancing on the stage" is a clause: it qualifies as a clause because it has a subject-predicate structure, although the subject is understood rather than overt.

In [2] "dancing" is not a clause but a verb phrase. It belongs to the sub-type 'participle VP', so I suppose you could call it a participial phrase.

"Married" in [3] is not a verb but an adjective so "happily married" is an adjective phrase.

In [4] "meat-eating" is not a phrase at all, but a compound adjective.